# Django FieldError at /admin/ in Multidropdown Filter

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

In the django i am geeting this error,

my models.py

```
class User(MasterDataBaseModel):
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=255,verbose_name=_("username"))
    gender = models.ForeignKey(Gender, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_("Gender"))
```

the admin.py

```
class Useradmin(DuplicateMixin, MasterDataBaseAdmin):
form = forms.UserForm
search_fields = ["user_name","Gender"]
ordering = ["user_name"]
list_filter = [
    "users_name",
    ("Gender",MultiSelectDropdownFilter), ]

list_display = [
    "user_name",
    "Gender",]
```

getting this error ,FieldError at /admin/registration/user/

Answer (score 0):

Did you register your class? You can use admin.register(User) decorator for this.
code:

```
 @admin.register(User)
 class Useradmin(admin.ModelAdmin, DuplicateMixin, MasterDataBaseAdmin):


    search_fields = ["user_name","Gender"]
    ordering = ["user_name"]
    list_filter = [
        "users_name",
        ("Gender",MultiSelectDropdownFilter), ]
    
    list_display = [
        "user_name",
        "Gender",]
```

Comment: i did that but getting the same filed/error/admin

Comment: What you are trying to achieve with UserForm?  If you want to display fields in admin panel I recommend to leave only list filter and list display vars.

Comment: ok, can i ask you why this Django FieldError at /admin/ error happens

Comment: Well, the problem is that django admin doesn't  recognize your admin fields.  I update my answer, try in this way please.